# Как сделать чтобы выводилась первая цена, а не все сразу

Tags: php, json, api

Есть Json запрос

```
<?php

$map = function($array, $from, $to){
    $result = [];
    if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)){
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from]?:null;
            $value = $element[$to]?:null;
            if($key && $value){
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};

$airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('/json/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=MOW&destination=AER&limit=1&token=*********");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *********"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$products=json_decode($response,true);
$replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($cities, $airlines){
    $response = $val;
    switch($key){case 'destination':
            $response = $cities[$val];break;
            case 'origin':
            $response = $cities[$val];break;
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}

?>
<?php
if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
?>
```

Есть ответ Json

```
{"success": true, "data": {"AER":{"0":{"price":3455,"airline":"WZ","flight_number":121,"departure_at":"2016-12-19T08:35:00Z","return_at":"2016-12-30T03:30:00Z","expires_at":"2016-11-26T12:06:18Z"},"1":{"price":5946,"airline":"NN","flight_number":349,"departure_at":"2017-02-18T15:45:00Z","return_at":"2017-02-20T12:15:00Z","expires_at":"2016-11-26T06:47:00Z"},"2":{"price":7897,"airline":"UT","flight_number":489,"departure_at":"2017-02-18T21:00:00Z","return_at":"2017-03-10T06:00:00Z","expires_at":"2016-11-26T10:54:50Z"}}}}
```

Мне нужно вывести только первый Price, я это делаю вот так

```
<?php echo $row['price'][0]; ?>&nbsp; RUB &nbsp; <?php
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Но выводятся все равно все Price. Как решить задачу? заранее спасибо за ответ, с уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите все данные в цикле, и по этому все выводит.

Не знаю все соль задачи, по этому, если вы хотите в цикле выбрать первую цену то, выбирайте в цикле выше:

```
if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
    foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
        var_dump($data[0]['price']);
        foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
        }
    }
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d184e46841b060cc250ae7702a532dca06d413cc)

Если товар один, то можно и просто:

```
$products['data']['AER'][0]['price'];
```

Comment: Все отлично только вот результат вот так высвечивается int(3455) а как сделать чтобы результат был без int и скобок? Заранее спасибо

Comment: эмм, ну как бы `var_dump` заменить на то что вам необходимо, `echo`, `print` ...

Comment: Вы гений, спасибо)